# Grove finger print sensor - how can i get an access to the template data of the finger print

Tags: arduino, sensors, fingerprint

I am trying to use the Grove fingerprint sensor on a project. I want to use the fingerprint data and find a way to put it in my own database but i am having trouble on getting the template data of the finger print. Please help me out on this.

1. Is there any way to get an access to the template data from the Grove fingerprint sensor?
2. If it cannot be accessed is there any other sensor where i can get an binary data of a finger print?